Why did my intro to quantum mechanics textbook negate one side of the Schrödinger Equation?
I was going through an intro to quantum mechanics textbook, and at one point, to define $\frac{∂\Psi}{∂t}$, the author says the Schrödinger Equation states that:
$\frac{∂\Psi}{∂t}=\frac{iℏ}{2m}\frac{∂^2\Psi}{∂x^2}-\frac{i}{ℏ}V\Psi$
Given the signs on the Schrödinger Equation, would it not be:
$\frac{∂\Psi}{∂t}=-\frac{iℏ}{2m}\frac{∂^2\Psi}{∂x^2}+\frac{i}{ℏ}V\Psi$
I would have written this off; however, a later practice question seems to rely on the negation of one side of the equation. Also, this is not meant to be the complex conjugate of the Schrödinger Equation, as he later defines it based on this negated version. I'm a high school student, so don't have any formal training in quantum physics, statistics, or complex analysis, so I don't entirely know what I am doing.
Am I missing something or just dumb?

The book is correct although usually the equation is wriiten as the book's multiplied by $i\hbar$ so the LHs is $i\hbar \partial_t\psi$ and the RHS $-(\hbar^2/2m) \partial_x^2\psi +V\psi$   I do not see where you got your equation from.

This question would be clearer if you stated what you think the signs in the usual form of the Schrödinger equation are.

Hint: $$1/i = -i$$

It seems that he multiplied both sides by i/ℏ, while I divided both by iℏ. I would expect these to give the same result, but looking at it they seem to not. Is dividing by i a no-no, or is my math even more incorrect? Again, little-to-no training with complex numbers, so I really appreciate the help.

The time-dependent Schrödinger equation
is usually written as
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi=
\left[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+V\right]\Psi.$$
Multiplying this by $-\frac{i}{\hbar}$ (and remembering $i^2=-1$) gives
$$\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial t}=
\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\Psi}{∂x^2}-\frac{i}{\hbar}V\Psi$$
as written in your textbook.

Ah, so you have to multiply by -i/ℏ, why can you not divide by i? I get that it gives a different answer, but I don't quite get why.

You can multiply by $-i/\hbar$ or divide by $i\hbar$. It is the same because $-i=1/i$.

Oh, I understand. I was under the assumption that 1/i = i. Thank you for the clarification.

@Kyle I was under the assumption that 1/i = i. Why? $1/i=i$ would mean that $i^2=1$ instead of $i^2=-1$.
